# How can I change my header to a moveble header when you scroll?

Tags: html, css

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(straat.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.hoofd-nav
{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
    
.hoofd-nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.hoofd-nav li a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 3px solid transparent; /* Remove wobble */
}
.hoofd-nav li a.actief
{
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.hoofd-nav li a:hover
{
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.logo img
{
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
    float: left;
}

body
{
    font-family: monospace;
}

.rij
{
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: auto;
}

.voorblad
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

h1
{
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 275px;       
}

.knop
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 550px;
}

.knop1
{
    border: 3px solid white;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.knop1
{
    background-color: darkorange;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title> Duco's Blog </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>   
<body> 
    <header>
        <div class="rij">
            <div class="logo">
            <img src="leeuw.png">
            </div>
        <ul class="hoofd-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="actief"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="index2.html"> Voorstellen </a></li>
            <li><a href="index3.html"> Hobby's </a></li>
            <li><a href="index4.html"> Toekomstdromen </a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="voorblad">
            <h1 id="iets"> Start De Reis</h1>
                
                <div class="knop">
                    <a href="index2.html" class="knop1"> Start </a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

So I am making a website for school and it has to be like a blog or something like that and I think It would be great if I have a moveable header when you scroll so does anyone now how I can change my header to a moveble header?

Thanks

My code: http://www.mediafire.com/file/64op22c06dc7ei6/Eindopdracht.rar/file
The snippet doesn't work correctly because I can't add 4 html files

I have 4 diffrent html files only to let the header work that if you click on one of the subjects its changes hte box maybe someone has a suggestion for that?

Comment: Like maybe someone know how I can make a code so I only need 1 html file instead of 4

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please consider clicking the [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53683702/edit) and create code snippets with the `{}` or `<>` button, instead of letting us download a file.

Comment: If i do that you dont see my background because it is a downloaded image andi cant upload 4 diffrent html files in 1 snippet

Comment: When you say "moveable header" I'm not 100% sure what you mean? Do you mean draggable or animated? P.S. No way I'm going to download a file from an external site. I was born at night, but not last night.